# Pseudo Code to Java translation error

Tags: java, pseudocode, code-translation

I have a question about an error when translating the pseudo code below into Java. There is no problem with the loss of accuracy because of truncation but a programming language issue that I can't seem to find.

I though the answer would be that the result of `Math.pow()` would be too much for a double (range from `4.94065645841246544e-324d` to `1.79769313486231570e+308d`. But apparently there is more wrong and I can't see it.

PSEUDO CODE

```
x = 7.0
y = x^1000.0
n = y truncated to an integer
```

converted to

JAVA

```
double x, y;
int n; 

x = 7.0;
y = Math.pow(x,1000.0);
n = (int)y;
```

Much appreciated, I'd really like to understand the issues here.

Comment: What error are you talking about?  There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: 7^1000 is about 1.25e845. It exceeds the range of double. long, 64bit integer, can express -9.2e18 to +9.2e18. 1.25e845 exceeds the range of long also.   This is problem of language limit of java, not the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do,

```
double x = 7.0;
double y = Math.pow(x, 1000.0); // <-- INFINITY
```

you do exceed the precision of `double` and you get [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY)

```
System.out.println(y);
```

Output is

```
Infinity
```

When you cast that to `int` you get [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) which is 2^31-1 or 2147483647. If you want to get a more convincing result you could use `BigInteger` like

```
int n = BigInteger.valueOf(7).pow(1000).intValue();
System.out.println(n);
```

Output is

```
432069569
```

Of course, the real result is obtained by

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(7).pow(1000));
```

Which results in a very big number indeed.

Comment: So, it's both the fact that y = infinity and you get the max integer value for n when casting. I didn't know the second occurs. Thanks so much.